# Modal Spark TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, modal-dialog, textarea, flash-builder

I want to make the background appear as if a modal window was opened but, instead of a window, I wnat to use Spark TextArea.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PopUpManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html) to create any IFlexDisplayObject as a modal view.

Example:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            import spark.components.TextArea;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var ta:TextArea = new TextArea();
                ta.width = 300;
                ta.height = 200;

                PopUpManager.addPopUp(ta, this, true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(ta);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button label="Click" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want TextArea to have it's own show effect? E.g. I want it to fade and slide to a certain place in my app but I want the background to be covered with the modal overlay. How will I do that?

Comment: You might find the SkinnablePopUpContainer component useful: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/SkinnablePopUpContainer